# Hurriedly vs Hurried

Tags: adverbs

> Maria unnecessarily picked a quarrel with Rani and left the party **hurried**.

Is this sentence OK? I think *hurriedly* should be used instead of *hurried*. Isn't it?

Comment: I wouldn't use either, *and immediately left the party* is better.

Comment: I have found the first one is right.But there needs an adverd to modify the verb left.Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, an adverb  modifies a verb, thus it should be "hurrriedly", but the better position is before the verb *"and hurriedly left the party"*

Comment: It should be *hurriedly* as the user above pointed out. But it is your choice to place the adverb where you want to. *hurriedly left the party* and *left the party hurriedly* are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the comments provides the right answer. I will summarize.

Short answer: in the provided example, **hurriedly** is correct, while **hurried** is not.

The following are all correct alternatives:

> Maria unnecessarily picked a quarrel with Rani and left the party **in a hurry**.

or:

> Maria unnecessarily picked a quarrel with Rani and **hurriedly** left the party.

or:

> Maria unnecessarily picked a quarrel with Rani and left the party.

or:

> Maria unnecessarily picked a quarrel with Rani and left the party **hurriedly**.